# objc[75927]: Class PFFile and objc[75927]: Class PFLogger is implemented in both One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined

Tags: swift, parse-platform, swift4

No errors in my code, but the console is printing the title of this post. I am using parse as a server. I am using this exact same code in an example video that i learned from on Udemy. Also None of my buttons are working when they are connected properly.

```
import UIKit

import Parse

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var signUpMode = true
var activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()

    @IBOutlet var emailTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var passwordTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var signUpOrLogin: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var changeSignUpMode: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var messageLabel: UILabel!

    func createAlert(title:String, message: String) {

        let alert  = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
            //self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        }))

        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func signUpOrLogin(_ sender: Any) {

        if emailTextField.text == "" || passwordTextField.text == "" {

            createAlert(title: "Error due to form", message: "Please enter an Email and Password.")

        } else {

            activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
            activityIndicator.center = self.view.center
            activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
            activityIndicator.style = UIActivityIndicatorView.Style.gray
            view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
            activityIndicator.startAnimating()
            UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()


            if signUpMode{

                let user = PFUser()

                user.username = emailTextField.text

                user.email = emailTextField.text

                user.password = passwordTextField.text

                user.signUpInBackground(block:{ (success, error) in

                    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()

                    UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()

                    if error != nil {

                        var displayErrorMessage = "Please try again later"

                        if let errorMessage = (error! as NSError).userInfo["error"] as? String {

                            displayErrorMessage = errorMessage
                            //This is the message that the console gives us
                        }

                        self.createAlert(title: "Signup Error", message: displayErrorMessage)

                    } else {

                        print("user signed up")

                    }
                })
            } else {
                //login mode
                PFUser.logInWithUsername(inBackground: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!) { (user, error) in

                    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()

                    UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
                    if error != nil{

                        var displayErrorMessage = "Please try again later"

                        if let errorMessage = (error! as NSError).userInfo["error"] as? String {

                            displayErrorMessage = errorMessage
                            //This is the message that the console gives us
                        }

                        self.createAlert(title: "Login Error", message: displayErrorMessage)

                    } else {

                        print("logged in")

                    }
                }
            }

        }

    }

    @IBAction func changeSignUpMode(_ sender: Any) {

        if signUpMode{
            //Change to Login Mode

            signUpOrLogin.setTitle("Log In", for: [] ) //empty array is default state again....

            changeSignUpMode.setTitle("Sign Up", for: [])

            messageLabel.text = "Don't have an account?"

            signUpMode = false

        } else {

            //Change to SignupMode
            signUpOrLogin.setTitle("Sign Up", for: [])

            changeSignUpMode.setTitle("Log In", for: [])

            messageLabel.text = "Already have an account?"

            signUpMode = true
        }
    }
```

Comment: I fixed formatting.

Comment: Thanks I see what you did, yeah im still unsure about the solution to this